# Formatter in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I just finished installing SonataNews with Formatter. But I can not configure a ckeditor even after the following steps:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#advanced-formatter-widget
[image]

Comment: Is the ivory/ckeditor present in your vendor ?

Comment: No, it dosent existe

Comment: But I have egeloen/ckeditor-bundle

Comment: Have you overided you default layout in including the javascript [as mentionned](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#sonata-admin-integration) ?

Comment: Yes I did it :/ . and there is a point, all of this path in this part are in bundles/
I don't have this folder

Comment: Have you install your vendor with composer update ?

Comment: Yes I did it, no change

Comment: did you do this ? https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/formatter_widget.html#sonata-admin-integration

Answer (score 0):

Install the sonata-project/formatter-bundle as mentioned here:
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/formatter/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Then add this line in your admin controller:

```
$formMapper->add('content', 'ckeditor', array());
```